# Spring Security - Query change in security-context.xml

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-security

Spring security when suppose to use database, found following queries to be descrbed in security-context.xml

```
users-by-username-query=
select username,password,enabled from authentication where username=? 

authorities-by-username-query=
select u.username, ur.authority from authentication u, authenticationrole ur 
where u.authenticationId = ur.authenticationId and u.username =?
```

it has two table authentication and authenticationrole

```
authentication -> authenticationid, username, password, ENABLED(0 / 1)

authenticationrole -> authenticationroleid, authenticationid, authority
```

Want to change these queries as per my db structure

```
user -> userid, username, password, userstatus(0 / 1)

role -> roleid, rolecode, rolename

userrole -> roleid, userid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**users-by-username-query**

```
select username,password, userstatus from user where username=?
```

**authorities-by-username-query**

```
   select user.username, role.rolename from 
   user join userrole on user.userid=userrole.userid 
   join role on userrole.roleid=role.roleid,
   where user.username=?
```